# Best Practices for Kafka Message Content?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Are there best practices or a standardized approach for message content in Kafka? ID vs Whole Document Vs Subset of Fields

Not finding any guidelines for this and the general advice seems to be "it depends". I see some pros and cons for all options in our microservice architecture.

Also, do people generally create whatever kind of message they need on a case by case basis or go with a standard message format for all types of messages? Like sending an ID to call the service it's from or sending all the information you need in the message itself or doing a combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation advocates for short messages. But I would suggest using whatever makes sense for your business case and overall architecture strategy. In our company we send very large messages through Kafka topics with long retention policy - seems to work fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's really true that "it depends" :-)
As Aleksey mentioned, Kafka is not mostly used for sending big messages and the body is just bytes so you can send whatever you want (binary, JSON, XML, ...).
There are also use cases where it could even make sense not using body at all tbh but headers. The headers section was added because it was missing but useful (as for other messaging protocols like AMQP 1.0).
Finally, having a standard message format for all types of messages could not work well when you have to address specific use cases. The different messages type is somehow addressed by having different topics (i.e. order topic, payment topic, ...) where for each topic, the messages have their own format quite different from the messages format on other topics.